# Method in [R] for arrays of data frames

Tags: r, dataframe

I am looking for a best practice to store multiple vector results of an evaluation performed at several different values. Currently, my working code does this:

```
q <- 55
value <- c(0.95, 0.99, 0.995)
a <- rep(0,q) # Just initialize the vector
b <- rep(0,q) # Just initialize the vector
for(j in 1:length(value)){
  for(i in 1:q){
    a[i]<-rnorm(1, i, value[j]) # just as an example function
    b[i]<-rnorm(1, i, value[j]) # just as an example function
  }
  df[j] <- data.frame(a,b)
}
```

I am trying to find the best way to store individual a and b for each value level

- To be able to iterate through the variable "value" later for graphing
- To have the value of the variable "value" and/or a description of it available

Comment: I think it is not clear what you are looking for. First, `value` does not contain `levels`, so please be careful with the terminology you are using. Second, you are not using data.frames at all. Third, if you just want to apply a function to the elements of `a` and `b`, you can use `sapply`.

Comment: Sorry about the value vs. levels, I drafted this then realized R uses levels as a keyword and tried to change it.

Comment: I used rnorm(1, i, value[j]) as a placeholder for a more complicated set of computations that aren't (imho) applicable to this question. What I'm trying to achieve is creating an object that will contain the data for all three calculated value datasets. This object will be passed to the reporting functions to create the graphs I need.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, so let me know if this is what you're looking for.

```
q = 55
value <- c(sd95=0.95, sd99=0.99, sd995=0.995)

a = sapply(value, function(v) {
  rnorm(q, 1:q, v)
})
```

In the code above, we avoid the inner loop by vectorizing. For example, `rnorm(55, 1:55, 0.95)` will give you 55 random normal deviates, the first drawn from a distribution with mean=1, the second from a distribution with mean=2, etc. Also, you don't need to initialize `a`.

`sapply` takes the place of the outer loop. It applies a function to each value in `value` and returns the three vectors of random draws as the data frame `a`. I've added names to the values in `value` and `sapply` uses those as the column names in the resulting data frame `a`. (It would be more standard to make `value` a list, rather than a vector with named elements. You can do that with `value <- list(sd95=0.95, sd99=0.99, sd995=0.995)` and the code will otherwise run the same.)

You can create multiple data frames and store them in a list as follows:

```
q <- list(a=10, b=20)
value <- list(sd95=0.95, sd99=0.99, sd995=0.995)

df.list = sapply(q, function(i) {
    sapply(value, function(v) {
      rnorm(i, 1:i, v)
    })
  })
```

This time we have two different values for `q` and we wrap the `sapply` code from above inside another call to `sapply`. The inner `sapply` does the same thing as before, but now it gets the value of `q` from the outer `sapply` (using the dummy variable `i`). We're creating two data frames, one called `a` and the other called `b`. `a` has 10 rows and `b` has 20 (due to the values we set in `q`). Both data frames are stored in a list called `df.list`.